# Reply to Graduate Admission offer

Tags: graduate-admissions, united-states

This question should link with the [question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/63946/how-to-write-the-graduate-coordinator-regarding-admission/63949#63949).

After I get the admission offer (**unofficial**), I replied Graduate Coordinator

> "Thank you very much for the offer. I will inform you the  decision
>   regarding admission offer around the end of March. I have already sent
>   the  official GRE(Subject + revised) and TOEFL-iBT score from ETS and
>   I will contact soon at my university to get  the official transcripts
>   to send your department. "

The professor replied:

> "Please do not send any official transcripts to the department. As soon as you notify us that you accept the offer,
>   the Graduate School will be informed and you will be contacted with
>   instructions on how and where to send official documents. The school
>   may not accept documents not sent directly to them."

Again I replied him

> "Thanks. I understand  you completely. "

My question is, as the admission offer was unofficial, I wanted to send all of the official documents and I will decide letter. Now will it be okay if I inform them the decisions after a month and send offical documents at that time?

Answer (score 4):

Wait until you receive your official offer. The offer letter will include all relevant instructions and deadlines for submitting official documents. If you do it before then, you risk doing it incorrectly. Assuming that your deadline to decide will be April 15, it is acceptable to submit everything in March.

Comment: I have received the full offer letter . The letter mentioned that  "The official certificate of admission will come from the university, after all official transcripts and  other necessary documents and test scores are received; until then, this offer is considered unofficial. "

Comment: This seems to be the timeline that they want: (1) You decide to attend that school (2) You tell them that you will be attending (3) They tell you how to submit official documents (4) You submit official documents (5) They send you a certificate of admission and confirm your enrollment. I'm guessing that they listed some deadline for telling them that you'd like to attend, but you could always e-mail them to confirm that.